Rest WebService in PHP with List of Object as input
I have the following class in php that I use to implement Rest Web service in PHP.
This is the file webApi.php
<?php

require './bootstrap.php';
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri = explode( '/', $uri );
if ((isset($uri[3]) && $uri[3] == 'saveArticoli')) {
    //echo "arrivato4";
    require './SaveArticoli.php';
    $objFeedController = new ArticoliController();
    $strMethodName = 'saveArticoli';
    //echo "arrivato5";
    $objFeedController->{$strMethodName}();
}else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    exit();
}


?>

This is the file SaveArticoli.php
    <?php
    require '../Connections/connessione.php';
    
    class ArticoliController extends BaseController
    
    {
    
      public function saveArticoli() 
        {

    
    }
}

?>

I need to implement a WebService to have in input a List of object. How can I do to make this?

"I need to implement a WebService to have in input a List of object" - I'm not sure what you mean by that? Do you want an endpoint that you can send a JSON payload that is a collection of objects to?

yes I should have in input a List of object

You can parse the entire POST body or individual POST parameters. If those don’t work for you we’ll need more information.
